# Sharing / Migrating Libraries files form 1 salesforce env to other.

Tags: salesforce-id, migration, libraries

Is their any way for Sharing / Migrating Libraries files form 1 salesforce env to other.  I have moved some class and Vf page from one env to other other and these class are using Libraries file.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about sharing but the simplest way to migrating required components from one env to other is using eclipse Force.com IDE.

You can deploy selected components from source organisation to target organisation. Select you  library files and by right click "Force.com | Deploy to server > and then provide target org credentials and follow instruction wizard provide.